# SQL Server : select from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database

Currently, this is the only way I know

```
Create @tempTable1

Insert into @tempTable1
    Exec mySP1 input1, input2

Create @tempTable2

Insert into @tempTable2
    Exec mySP2 input1, input2

Select *
from @tempTable1 as A
join @tempTable2 as B on A.input1 = B.input1
```

Which is very inconvenient because first I would have to create barebone temp tables then insert into, once finished I must remove temp tables. Is there a better way to for me to do something like this instead?

```
Select * 
from (Exec mySP1 input1, input2) as A
join (Exec mySP2 input1, input2) as B on A.input1 = B.input1
```

Comment: *once finished I must remove temp tables* - you don't need to "remove" an @tableVar?

Comment: *is very inconvenient* - perhaps yoir things that are stored procedures should not be stored procedures - there's nothing like picking the wrong tool for a job then trying to fudge around every limitation the decision throws in your path. Post the actual sprocs so we can see

Comment: It's actually a little bit more complex, I simplified it here so I can ask the question.  My actual stored procedure takes 4 inputs, returns the highest record entries.  I just want to check with you guys to see if this is even possible.  If not, that's alright too.

Comment: If you want to use a `SELECT` - you might need to convert your stored procedures to table-valued stored **functions** instead. With stored **procedures**, your current approach (with a temp table or table variable) is the best you can do

Comment: Yes table-valued functions would be a better fit, depending on what the code in the procedure is doing. You can also create #temptables in the outer scope and populate them in the inner scope, but more detail is needed to be any more precise.

Comment: You can use [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and execute the stored procedure. Note you need to enable [ad hoc distributed queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/ad-hoc-distributed-queries-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) in order to use openrowset

Comment: Thanks Squirrel, I'll definately gonna try it out on Monday when I get back to work.

Comment: why not using TVF(Table_value functions)? they have the capability of join with each other/

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2022/02/08/sql-server-using-stored-procedure-in-select-statement/

Not sure why this blog didn't show up at work today but I'm going to print this out and try it out on Monday.

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
'server=localhost;trusted_connection=yes;',
'EXEC Exec mySP1 input1, input2') as A
join
OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
'server=localhost;trusted_connection=yes;',
'EXEC Exec mySP2 input1, input2') as B on A.input1 = B.input1
```

Any comment ?

Comment: It is a contrived approach, requires additional documentation and administration (yeah - that disaster recovery plan which you likely don't have needs to be updated), can be inefficient. If you need to join resultsets like these on a consistent basis, that suggests your code design is the problem.